# Mustache tempale. How to output array of arrays?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, mustache

How to render this structure:

```
[
    'something1' => 
        (
            ['lol' => 'str1' 'stuff' => 'str2'], 
            ['lol' => 'str3' 'stuff' => 'str4']
        ),
    'something2' => 
        (
            ['lol' => 'str5' 'stuff' => 'str6'],
            ['lol' => 'str8' 'stuff' => 'str9']
        )
]
```

Need get string key 'something1' and keys value 'lol','stuff'

Comment: https://github.com/janl/mustache.js#non-empty-lists

Comment: use array_keys()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use for each with mustache javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798084/how-to-use-for-each-with-mustache-javascript)

Comment: @admcfajn no, he have object keys its easy to use. To me need output 
 word 'something1' and iteration inside array for get value attributes lol, stuff.

Comment: What have you actually tried thus far? You haven't provided your template or render.